# Enable RUN history

Tags: windows, windows-8

My computer does not store the history of the entries entered in RUN (<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
[image]

Thus, how to enable Windows to store the history?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Right-click on taskbar
2. Go to Properties
3. On *Properties → Start Menu* tab (in Windows 8, it is called *Jump Lists*)
4. Check *Store and display a list of recently opened programs* under *Privacy*.

Answer (score 21):

The location of this setting has changed in Windows 10.

1. Open the Start menu
2. Select *Settings*
3. Select the *Personalization* button
4. Select *Start* in the left column
5. Toggle *Show most used apps* to the *On* position

Comment: If *Show most used apps* is greyed out you can re-enable it by setting `Settings -> Privacy -> General -> Let Windows track app launches to improve Start and search results` back to `On`.

Comment: Instruction w screenshots how to enable greyed out option is at https://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-most-used-apps-settings-is-disabled-greyed-out

Comment: The corresponding registry key for future me: ````HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Start_TrackProgs````

Answer (score 17):

#### Enable or Disable App Launch Tracking

- **Windows 10**
  Settings > Privacy > General >
  Let Windows track app launches to improve Start and search results
- **Windows 11**
  Settings > Privacy & security > General > Let Windows improve Start and search results by tracking app launches

Comment: Also correct for `10 home`.

Comment: Also works on Win 10 Version 1803 (10.0.17134.407).