# How to enable run menu history in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Whatever I type into "Run" in Windows 10, for example "regedit" or "gpedit.msc", my Windows 10 never saves this history. I hate to type these things again and again. Is there a way to enable run menu history in Windows 10?

Comment: Try this Go to Start Menu - -> Personalization -- > Start - -> Check "Show Recently opened items in jump list on start or the taskbar". Taken Source : http://superuser.com/questions/607008/enable-run-history