# Can't use the "Run" (Win + R) Mirror

Tags: windows-8

It just happened today, without anything that I did. When pressing for example the <kbd>H</kbd> key, will return me a lot of http sites I visited. Something automatically presses <kbd>↑</kbd>. When there is no list something automatically selects the first entry and disselects it and my typed in text comes in. After a short time it makes the process again.
Here is a gif of it:

[image]

Also it happens on the menu screen in Windows 8. Beneath there is a scrollbar. When trying to scroll to the right, it gets back to default automatically, as it can be seen on here:

[image]

*In programs like paint.NET or Microsoft Word or any programs that is not a browser, the scrollbar plays crazy. Only YouTube has a problem in any browser, too. I can't use the sound regulator, as it automatically goes down when hovering.*

*It has nothing to do with my keyboard because it turned out that it is a software error by unpluging the keyboard and testing the other alternatives

Thanks for helping

Comment: You need to explain what your problem is using words.  Your animation does not provide any clue what your problem actually is.

Comment: Instead of being sorry click the Edit button and refine your question. Does it happen in other applications? What are you actually pressing to get that kind of disco and what were you trying to do?

Comment: As a temporary fix, you might want to see if you can disable this list - https://superuser.com/q/607008/302907

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still this bug don't only affects the Run Mirror, but many more. Still, it helped me to a fraction of 100%.

Comment: @ThaumicTom - Have you tried using a different keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Your keyboard is misbehaving. It looks like the down arrow is stuck. Check the arrow keys and make sure they are not stuck in any way. Most likely your keyboard is bad and will need to be replaced.

You can confirm this with a [Keyboard Tester](https://www.passmark.com/products/keytest.htm) which will show you the stuck key.

If this is a laptop, you’ll need to service the laptop to remove and replace the keyboard.

Comment: I tested all buttons on my keyboard, none seem to stuck. (It's a normal keyboard, no laptop)

Comment: @ThaumicTom How did you test? Did you actually TEST the keyboard with the tester I recommended, or plug in a DIFFERENT keyboard? There's only one reason this happens - and it's because your keyboard is bad.

Comment: I used the Tester.

Comment: Then the tester is either not working as intended or you may be misinterpreting the results. This is simple to test, either plug in a different keyboard, or you said the volume slider goes down when you click on it, so unplug your keyboard and click on your volume slider. Does it still go down on its own?

Comment: Apparently it has nothing to do with my Keyboard. The problems are still there, with or without keyboard.

Comment: @ThaumicTom Ok. Then unplug the mouse while you try typing in the run box. It would be the first time I’ve seen a mouse do this. But there is a first for everything. To confirm, are both mouse and keyboard USB? Are they wireless?

Comment: Okay, this is werid, I have a wired keyboard and a wireless mouse. It turns out that unplugging the mouse helps. Now doing WIN+R will open the Run Mirror and do everything flawless. Scrolling on Windows 8 menu works fine, too. Now pluging the mouse in, everything works normally. So it comes out that I have to unplug and then plug my USB to the mouse to fix this problem.

Comment: Ok. So ultimately the mouse is misbehaving. That’s a first I’ve seen to do something like this. But it makes sense. You’ll probably need to replace the mouse if it continues to act up. But it appears it was a sync issue between the receiver and the mouse that you reset when unplugging it.