# How to delete Run history in Windows?

Tags: command-line

Whenever I press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> , **`Run dialog box`** appears so that commands such as `temp` or `%temp%` can be typed in. I did this in order to delete temp files, etc.

When I again press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, the old commands used are still listed in the box.

How do I prevent this history from recurring ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable RUN history](https://superuser.com/questions/607008/enable-run-history)

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @davidmneedham, he is asking for something like `Disable RUN history` not what you mentioned as the link ?

Comment: It's a checkbox of `Store and display a list of recently opened programs`. If you click it, it enables the history. If you don't click it, it disables the history. Do we need a question and answer for both?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent history from recurring this way :

1. Open `Registry Editor` by typing **`regedit`** in the `Run dialog box`
2. Find this :

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU

3. In the right panel, you will find the entire history. Select all the strings `except the Default string` and delete them.
4. And Your' done.

Comment: This will only clear the history. If you create more entries, they will reappear in the registry.

Comment: This will do the trick for the commands that have previously been inputted but it will not prevent them from reoccurring.  I am trying to find a way to prevent the run dialog from retaining history.